# Best practices of converting an already created site into Craft CMS?

Tags: craft-features, migration

We have various clients who already have websites but would like us to optimize them a little bit and set them up on craft.

Is there a more efficient way to do this than just hand coding all of the PHP and blocks for every page to align to be editable on craft?

Comment: What CMS are they currently using? Or is it just completely custom PHP?

Comment: Currently no CMS. Just HTML and CSS. Kind of old school.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not already on a CMS, I'd recommend migrating to Craft sooner rather than later. Sounds like you're definitely planning on migrating to Craft, so I see no valuable reason to delay.

**Pros of migrating now:**

- Awesome Craft features, like Matrix
- Plugins
- Twig

**Cons of migrating later:**

- More legacy code to port
- More legacy data to restructure

You'll notice that both of those lists reinforce the idea of migrating now. ;)